# Point positioning inside rectangle with only two known vertexes

Tags: geometry

I'm working on a js widget, and I've come across a positioning problem, which I can't seem to solve with my limited geometry knowledge or by help of Wikipedia/google.

I have a quadrilateral rectangle, which is positioned at an angle. I know its two opposite vertexes and width/height ratio. And there's a point on it, which coordinates I also know. I need to find how far (in %s of width/height) is that point from rectangle's sides. Is it possible to do so?
[image]

Comment: You’ve got a bit of a problem here because the aspect ratio and endpoints of a diagonal don’t identity the rectangle uniquely: if you flip the above rectangle about its known diagonal, you get another rectangle that fits your description. Besides that, the measurement you’ve described is ill-defined: _which_ sides to you want to measure from? The diagram is suggestive, but you need a more precise description of what exactly it is that you’re measuring taking into account all of the possible orientations. For instance, what if the top diagonal point is to the left of the bottom one?

Answer (score -1):

Let $(x_0,y_0)$ the coords of the lowest point, and $(x_1,y_1)$ the coords of the highest.  Let also $\alpha$ the angfle formed by the line passing throught $(x_0,y_0)$ parallel to $h$. We can write the equation of this line as:
$$L_h: y-y_0=\tan(\alpha)(x-x_0)$$
Now, we have to find the equation of the line paasing throught $(x_1,y_1)$ and parallel to $w$. We have:
$$L_w: y-y_1=-\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}(x-x_1)$$
Let $(X,Y)$ the coords of the fixed point. Now, we have done, because we can use the distance formula. Let $\delta_h$ the distance of the fixed point from the line $L_h$, we have:
$$\delta_h=\frac{|\tan(\alpha)X-Y+y_0-\tan(\alpha)x_0|}{\sqrt{\tan^2(\alpha)+1}}$$
Let $\delta_w$ the distance of the fixed point from the line $L_w$, we have:
$$\delta_w=\frac{|-\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}X-Y+\frac{x_1}{\tan(\alpha)}+y_1|}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{\tan(\alpha)}\right)^2+1}}$$

Comment: Why have you putted a $-1$ what is wrong?

Comment: @Dmitry Oleinik: if this answer has been useful, maybe a $+1$ or a favourite answer?